# End Timeline in SwiftUI with a button?

Tags: swiftui, timeline, stopwatch

I have this code for a stopwatch with TimelineView. I want to achieve, that by pressing the Button "End" the timer will end. I thought that by setting back the variable elapsedTime = 0 I can solve this, but I get an error. How do I add a button which resets this stopwatch only when pressed a button? And for instance I have a TabView in Paging style It should still continue when swiping to another page.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {
    var date: Date
    var showSubseconds: Bool
    var fontWeight: Font.Weight = .bold
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 8.0, watchOS 8.0, iOS 15.0, *) {
            //The code from here is mostly from https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009
            TimelineView(MetricsTimelineSchedule(from: date)) { context in
                ElapsedTimeView(elapsedTime: -date.timeIntervalSinceNow, showSubseconds: context.cadence == .live)
            }
        } else {
            Text(date,style: .timer)
                .fontWeight(fontWeight)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 8.0, watchOS 8.0, iOS 15.0,*)
private struct MetricsTimelineSchedule: TimelineSchedule {
    var startDate: Date
    
    init(from startDate: Date) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        
    }
    
    func entries(from startDate: Date, mode: TimelineScheduleMode) -> PeriodicTimelineSchedule.Entries {
        PeriodicTimelineSchedule(from: self.startDate, by: (mode == .lowFrequency ? 1.0 : 1.0 / 30.0))
            .entries(from: startDate, mode: mode)
    }
}
struct ElapsedTimeView: View {
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var showSubseconds: Bool = false
    var fontWeight: Font.Weight = .bold
    @State private var timeFormatter = ElapsedTimeFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(NSNumber(value: elapsedTime), formatter: timeFormatter)
            .fontWeight(fontWeight)
            .onChange(of: showSubseconds) {
                timeFormatter.showSubseconds = $0
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                timeFormatter = ElapsedTimeFormatter()
            })
//        Button("End") {
//            elapsedTime = 0
//        }
    }
}

class ElapsedTimeFormatter: Formatter {
    let componentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return formatter
    }()
    var showSubseconds = true

    override func string(for value: Any?) -> String? {
        guard let time = value as? TimeInterval else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let formattedString = componentsFormatter.string(from: time) else {
            return nil
        }

        if showSubseconds {
            let hundredths = Int((time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)) * 100)
            let decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
            return String(format: "%@%@%0.2d", formattedString, decimalSeparator, hundredths)
        }

        return formattedString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying it with my online converter, but you could do a

```
var time : TimeInterval = 1.2
print("\(time) is time...")

time = time - time
print("\(time) is new time...")
```

So everytime you click the "End" Button, you just delete your time value with its actual value.

edit: in your case you need elapsedTime of course :-)